# adding JSON length

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a function that is called multiple times which uses jquery to fetch different JSON from an API.

I have been trying to get a cumulative count of part of that JSON. Here is sort of what I have:

```
getTheData(aBlah,bBlah,cBlah);

getTheData(aStuff,bStuff,cStuff);

function getTheData(aBlah,bBlah,cBlah){
     $.ajax({
    url: 'https://my.url.com/aBlah?bBlah?cBlah',
    type:"GET",
    data: { fields: "subdata" },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType:"application/json",
    jsonpCallback: myCallback,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.subdata.length);
        'the rest of the code'
    });
}
```

I am trying to get a cumulative total of data.subdata.length but I'm not sure how to go about getting it.

Comment: There is syntax error in the code you have added.

Comment: You can create a counter as a global variable to store the length. Initialize it as 0, then every ajax response adds its length in the counter value. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use case for [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```
var closure = function(){

   var counter = 0;

  function getTheData(aBlah,bBlah,cBlah){
     $.ajax({
    url: 'https://my.url.com/aBlah?bBlah?cBlah',
    type:"GET",
    data: { fields: "subdata" },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType:"application/json",
    jsonpCallback: myCallback,
    success: function(data){
        counter += data.subdata.length;
        'the rest of the code'
     });
 }

 function getcount(){
     return counter;
  }

   return {
      getTheData:getTheData,
      getcount:getcount
   }
};

var myClosure= closure();
myClosure.getTheData(aBlah,bBlah,cBlah);
myClosure.getTheData(aStuff,bStuff,cStuff);

var count  = myClosure.getcount();
```

This helps control the scope of the counter variable. So you can do things like:

```
var myClosure= closure();
myClosure.getTheData(aBlah,bBlah,cBlah);
myClosure.getTheData(aStuff,bStuff,cStuff);

var count  = myClosure.getcount();

//counter in the new closure is zero
var newClosure = closure();

newClosure.getTheData(aBlah,bBlah,cBlah);
newClosure.getTheData(aStuff,bStuff,cStuff);

var totallyNewCount  = myClosure.getcount();
```